# BlackDuck and Power BI

Tags: powerbi, blackduck

I would like to connect from Power BI to BlackDuck using Rest API.

Initially, I would like to do everything using Power Query.
I just started exploring the possibilities of how to retrieve data without using a PostgreSQL database of the BlackDuck.

Maybe you had an experience of how to authenticate BlackDuck?
Maybe you have such experience and can share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested using API, but the easiest way was connected to PostgreSQL ( synopsis support  helped with it)

About API

1. need to get bearer token

create function (ex name GetToken):

```
    ()=>
    let
    
    url = "https://XXX.blackduck.com/api/tokens/authenticate",
    headers = [
       #"Accept" = "application/vnd.blackducksoftware.user-4+json",
       #"Authorization"= token XXXXXXXXXXX
       
       ],
    
    PostData=Json.FromValue([Authorization =  prToken]), 
    
    response = Web.Contents( url, 
              [ Headers = headers,
                Content = PostData]),
    
    Data = Json.Document(response),
    
    access_token="Bearer "&Data[bearerToken]
    
    
    in
    access_token

// where XXXXXXXXXXX  is your token from BlackDuck
```

it helps you to get Bearer token

2. as example to get information about project

   let

   ```
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://xxxxx.app.blackduck.com/api/projects", 
    [Headers=[Accept="application/vnd.blackducksoftware.project-detail-4+json",
    Authorization = GetToken()]]))
   ```

   in
   Source[totalCount]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, though what I could understand from their synopsis community, you cannot authenticate like this and you need to use their postgres DB

Comment: Hi Tardox, I ended up writing to technical support synopsis and they gave me access to the database. They use Postgres SQL and I create ODBC connections.
They helped me with all the settings
This turned out to be an easier way to get all the data without  using API and pagination